# Reload Links from a .blend Automatically

Tags: eevee-render-engine, blend-files, linked-data, outliner

I´m working on a small project in Blender. In this projekt I linked an object from another blend file. The problem is that I can only manually reload the data from this other blend file. Is it possible that Blender do this for example every 10 seconds automatically? I use Blender 2.81[image]

I hope you can help me.